# How do I get templated values in uri tag for http-client-requests metrics using ReactiveFeignClient?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, webclient, metrics, reactive-feign-client

We are using Spring Boot 2.7.8 and the micrometer-registry-prometheus dependency to capture metrics.

We use feign-reactor-webclient:3.2.6 to call out to another service. The metrics being generated by this call contain the actual values in the URI instead of the templated values.

For example, in the `/actuator/prometheus` endpoint, I see entries like this:
`http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="someClient",method="GET",status="200",uri="/person/lookup?firstName=Tony&lastName=Soprano",} 1.0`

I would expect to see the variable names rather than the values, like this:

`http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="someClient",method="GET",status="200",uri="/person/lookup?firstName={firstName}&lastName={lastName}",} 1.0`

Is there a way to get the default `http.client.requests` metric values to use the templated values for the URI tag?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here.

I haven't deployed the change to the production environment yet, but changing the feign-micrometer version locally (from 11.6 to 11.8) was enough to store the template, without changing any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The Reactive Feign package `com.playtika.reactivefeign:feign-reactor-spring-cloud-starter` contains a property called `reactive.feign.metrics.enabled`, which is disabled by default, but when enabled will record metrics with the URI template. You can read https://github.com/PlaytikaOSS/feign-reactive/tree/develop/feign-reactor-spring-configuration for more details.

Related Issues:

- https://github.com/PlaytikaOSS/feign-reactive/issues/474
- https://github.com/PlaytikaOSS/feign-reactive/issues/77

Related Code:

- https://github.com/PlaytikaOSS/feign-reactive/blob/baba570b5039c649d5487883f3db1e183026773a/feign-reactor-spring-configuration/src/main/java/reactivefeign/spring/config/ReactiveFeignClientsConfiguration.java#L72-L78

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).